# C++ rendering or game engine for Android.

Tags: c++, android, game-engine, rendering-engine

I'm developing an Android application and I need to use a render engine to show some objects that I made with Blend.

I'm wondering if there is a C++ game engine or render engine to show my models.

Is there anyone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at http://www.cuteandroid.com/open-source-android-2d-or-3d-game-engine-for-android-developers-plus for game engines.

Just for rendering, it looks like this might help: http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2010/05/17/loading-3d-models-with-the-min3d-framework-for-android/